# How to SSH into a seperate Gitlab instance's runner

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have two Gitlab runner instances on my server, both of which have a gitlab runner. They are both named "gitlab-runner". Whenever I SSH into a gitlab runner using the command `sudo su - gitlab-runner` I always get into the first instance's runner. How do I get access to the other one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding, you are running two gitlab runners in the same server. I would modify the `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` file and assign the runners different names.

```
vi /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml
```

For example,

```
[[runners]]
  name = "gitlab-runner-1"
  url = "https://your.url.com/"
  token = "your-token"
  executor = "docker"

  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "openjdk:11-jdk-slim-sid"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
    limit = 1

[[runners]]
  name = "gitlab-runner-2"
  url = "https://your.url.com/"
  token = "your-token"
  executor = "docker"

  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "openjdk:11-jdk-slim-sid"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
    limit = 1
```

After modifying the config, you will have to restart the gitlab-runner. The following command may help.

```
service gitlab-runner restart
```